# Telerik Editor Comes up Disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Editor (Asp.net Telerik MVC 3) that I am using to allow a user to add an item description. When the editor comes up, It is always disabled. While looking at it using the dev tool (DOM Explorer) on IE, I notice this line of code below. I can't figure out where it came from.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('BookDescription-value').style.display='none'</script>
```

To get around it, I added a JQuery function that enables the text editor as soon as it loads. It works fine except the tools are still disabled. I cannot make the text bold, underline, or use any other options specified on the tool. What am I doing wrong here?

```
//Reference to JQuery and stylesheet

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

//JQuery Function to enable editor
$(function () {
      //this line of code enable the editor text 
       $('#BookDescription-value').css('display', '');
     //I tried the lines of code below to enable the editor's tool bar with no luck.
     // Looking at the DOM Explorer tool, I don't see anything else that would disabled it.
        $('#BookDescription').css('display', '');
        $('.t-input').css('display', '');
        $('.t-editor-button').css('display', '');
        $('.t-widget t-editor t-header').css('display', '');
    });


//Editor 

@(Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.BookDescription)
                    .Encode(true)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:310px;", id = "BookDescription" })
                    .Tools(tools => tools
                        .Clear()
                        .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough().Subscript().Superscript().Separator()
                        .FontName().FontSize()
                        .FontColor().BackColor().Separator()
                        .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull().Separator()
                        .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList().Separator()
                        .Indent().Outdent().Separator()
                        )
                )
```

Comment: I don´t know if that matters but what about using the jquery version that comes with the telerik package you are using?  I have sometimes had problem with jquery version mismatch if I include different version. I´m just sayin.